# Directory structure and script arguments

Tags: url

I'll often see a URL that looks something like this:

```
site.com/articles/may/05/02/2011/article-name.php
```

Surely all of those subdirectories don't actually exist? It seems like it would be a huge redundancy, even if it was only an identical index file in every directory. To change anything you'd have to change every single one.

I guess my question is, is there some more elegant way that sites usually accomplish this?

Comment: By accomplish, do you mean to have the URL appear as you indicated above without actually structuring the directories that way?

Comment: I guess so. Some sites have so many thousands of articles, I just have a hard time imagining they exist in literal directories with files in each directory, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: If it were me, unless there was a good reason to have them all split up like that, I would have articles in one directory with their title giving the date info e.g. /articles/20110502_article-name.php

FWIW using YYYYMMDD means that files will always be ordered chronologically, even when ordered alphabetically.  This may or may not be a good thing if you have thousands of files, but it is excellent for image files.

Comment: See [Using Permalinks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks).

Comment: That's what I was looking for Dan, thanks! I had a feeling it was some Apache trick.

Comment: It is more common to see the "date" portion of the URL ordered the other way round eg. `/2011/02/05` - this provides a more logical structure for blogs, where entries are often arranged chronologically. Also note (as suggested by dan's permalink link), URLs and file system paths are two distinct entities. One might be mapped quite closely to the other, but this is not necessarily the case.

Comment: This was answered by user Dan in the comments: it's accomplished with the Apache mod_rewrite module. That will be enough for me to research the rest. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The subject you need to look into is called a `Rewrite engine`.

Basically, a dynamically generated page (eg a CMS page) needs to get parameters sent to it via the URL so that it knows what content to display.  For example, if a site only needs to know the article id in order to get that article's content from the database, then that page may initially have the URL site.com?id=24.

A rewrite engine could tidy that URL up so that it becomes site.com/24 or site.com/anything/24.  It just needs to know the "24"

It could even remove the id, just so long as a database query could work it out from its replacement.  For example... site.com/articletitle could allow a database query to ask "what is the id of the article with the title articletitle", before generating that page.

The example you give is pretty poor, as the date is back-to-front.  However, the wikipedia entry has some nice examples of it in proper use:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine

(It is very unlikely that a static site would use such a directory structure)

Answer (score 0):

Actually these are often blog sites and often with static rather than dynamic content, though not always. The URL you are referring to is automatically maintained by the software which creates, recreates, or updates the site according to what is in it's database. The URL structure is often an option. I do not see the advantage to having a directory path that is a date other than allowing for topics with similar or identical article names which can often happen on a blog - especially a blog where more than one person participates in.